# I'm trying to rewrite a sef url into a plain url using nginx

Tags: php, joomla, nginx, url-rewriting

I have the rewrite code as shown below. I'm trying to do a sort of SEF reversal. This is a quick fix till i can figure out a better way to do this in my application. Obviously, this leads to an internal redirect cycle?.

Can someone please help me correct this or at least explain why its leading to a redirect cycle.

> rewrite ^/tools/app/(.*)$ /tools/app?action=$1;

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to add a [break](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#break) at the end of the line

```
rewrite ^/tools/app/(.*)$ /tools/app?action=$1 break;
```

Comment: According to the docs, that should work but it turns out that the internal redirect was failing. What eventually worked was to do a 302 redirect i.e
    rewrite ^/tools/app/(.*)$ http://location/tools/app?action=$1 break;. 
    This is ugly so i ended up taking another approach specific to my project.

Comment: This will lead to an endless loop, in combination with `try_files $uri $uri/ ...;`. For this reason you should try to include all location blocks that apply to your rewrite problem.